# How to Print with Margins

Tags: c#, printing

I am making a Wordpad program. I am making this feature in which you click this button, and it prints to your default printer. I have done some research, and I found some functional code that prints to my printer:

```
private void buttonPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string print = "" + textBody.Text;

        PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
        p.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
        {
            e1.Graphics.DrawString(print, new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new     SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));
        };
        try
        {
            p.Print();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Exception Occured While Printing", ex);
        }
    }
```

This works currently, but I was wondering if I could make it WITH margins, which it does not have now. All it does is this:

```
<Top of Page>
<Message>
```

There are no margins on the top, sides (left,right), and bottom.  How can I modify my code to have margins?

Comment: Wordpad uses RichTextBox, (almost) the same one you have in the toolbox.  Printing its content so the text appears exactly the same on paper is a bit involved, but covered very well in this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996492.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `PrintDocument` you can set the [`Margins`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.pagesettings.margins(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `DefaultPageSettings` object:

```
Margins margins = new Margins(100,100,100,100);
p.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = margins;
```